# Android screen orientation issue in 8.1.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, android-orientation, android-8.1-oreo

Am having issue in Android OS 8.1.0

- Start a portrait activity (portrait declare on manifest)
- Start a landscape activity (landscape declare on manifest)
- Finish the landscape activity
- Portrait activity is showed again but the orientation start flipping: first in portrait mode, then landscape mode and finally portrait again.

I had observed this issue in google pixel 2 xl device with OS version 8.1.0 onwards ( issue present in Android P developer preview1 also)

i saw someone posted in google groups also

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69168442

but didn't get any fix, how can i fix this issue.?

My application is hybrid application (cordova) , I also tried to replicate issue in native android but issue is not there in native android sample app