# Android 8.1 orientation issues in Fragment

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying to set one particular fragment orientation as Landscape mode. I have added  `setRetainInstance(true);` in **onCreate** method.

I have added `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);` in **onCreateView** method.

It is working fine with 7.1 and lesser versions. But it is not working with 8.1.

I have also tried the following links.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228194/android-8-1-screen-orientation-issue-flipping-to-landscape-a-portrait-screen?rq=1)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293016/android-screen-orientation-issue-in-8-1-0) and many other solutions.
But those solutions were applicable for activity. In my case, I am using a fragment. Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

I have the following code in my manifest.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeScreen.view.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest look the Activity who contain the fragment and check if you have the following string:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Remove it. It prevent to override landscape layout

Comment: I have the following code in my manifest.    <activity
            android:name=".activity.HomeScreen.view.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

Comment: Hi @Legion. I have updated my question also. I don't have configChanges in my manifest. Please let me know if you have any idea to solve this issue.

Comment: Not sure that can help you.... but can you try to [handle it by yoursealf instead](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)? Seems odd, your code should work even in android 8.1 and higher :(

Answer (score 0):

Above code given by you in onCreateView method is working fine with fragment in both Android 8 oreo and android 9 pie.

If you haven't added onPause() in fragment please add

```
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
  }
```

It's not required to set `setRetainInstance(true);` in onCreate() method for the above versions.

Check if it's a particular phone issue and please check if auto rotate is disabled in that phone.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried adding orientation in onPause as well. I have also tried with different devices. Still the problem exists.